# Kendo UI Date Picker + AngularJS. On initialisation datepicker is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

Here is my code:

http://dojo.telerik.com/@CarloCruz/IjEZa

On initial load, the datepicker is empty.

If you remove ng-model from the directive template, the datepicker works like it should with it's initial value, but changing the datepicker doesn't trigger the form to be dirty.

How do i set the initial value and be able to trigger the $dirty of the angular form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the directives are wrapped (your custom one is wrapping the telerik one which wrappes the jquery one). Just change it manually like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/angular">
     <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />

  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
 <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">            
  <div ng-form="testform">
    {{testform.$dirty}}
    {{dateAttach}}<br />
    <my-datepicker form="testform" ng-model="dateAttach" required></my-datepicker>
  </div>   
 </div>
 </div>

 <script>
   angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"])
       .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
          $scope.dateAttach = new Date(1444015467000);
       }).controller('DatePickerCtrl', [
        '$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('date', function(oldVal, newVal) {
              if(oldVal != newVal){
                $scope.form.$dirty = true;
              }
            });              
        }
    ]).directive('myDatepicker', [
        function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
              scope: {
                date: '=ngModel',
                form: '='
              },
            controller: 'DatePickerCtrl',
                template: '{{date}}<br /><input kendo-date-picker="datePicker" k-ng-model="date" k-ng-delay="date"/>'
            };
         }            
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @diana, but your solution doesn't cause the form to become $dirty when changing the date picker.

Comment: @CarloCruz sorry, my mistake, just missed the fact that you need dirty form, check the edit version for solution.